# How to restrict RDS connection using IRSA?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I am trying to connect to RDS using IRSA from a pod. I want to restrict access to RDS using IRSA. But even after adding IRSA, I am able to connect to mysql from any pod.

IAM policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "rds:*",
                "rds-db:connect"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:rds:us-west-2:xxxx:db:database-2-instance-1"
        }
    ]
}
```

IRSA:

```
eksctl create iamserviceaccount \
  --name mysqlaccesssa \
  --namespace namespace2 \
  --cluster cluster12 \
  --attach-policy-arn arn:aws:iam::xxxx:policy/radtestrds \
  --approve
```

pod definition:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mysql-client
  namespace: namespace2
spec:
  serviceAccountName: mysqlaccesssa
  containers:
  - image: mysql:8
    command:
      - sleep
      - "3600"
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: busybox
  restartPolicy: Always
```

When trying to connect to the RDS instance from a pod from different namespace which is not added with IRSA, it still works.

```
kubectl exec -it mysql-client  -n namespace1 -- bash
bash-4.4#  mysql -h database-2-instance-1.xxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com -uadmin -ppassword
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 3266
Server version: 8.0.32 Source distribution
```

Any pointers on why its working?